# How to return the first matching value of a subquery based on two values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that I need to bring order number into from a subquery. My subquery has these columns:

- item_number
- warehouse
- order_number
- delivery_date

My dataset is currently sorted by delivery_date using ORDER BY
because I need the order that will be delivered first. I need to grab the first order_number that appears for each item_number & warehouse in my outer query.

My dataset is currently sorted by delivery_date using ORDER BY
because I need the order that will be delivered first. I need to grab the first order_number that appears for each item_number & warehouse in my outer query.

I tried DISTINCT and TOP 1 but they didn't work. I'm using MS SQL Server (T-SQL?) so unfortunately I can't use DISTINCT ON. I think I also tried to use a CASE statement in my outer query. It was something like, where "oq" = outer query and "sq" = subquery:
`FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN oq.item_number = sq.item_number AND oq.warehouse = sq.warehouse THEN sq.order_number ELSE NULL END) AS 'order_number`

I think that didn't work because I didn't use FIRST_VALUE correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your tag is `mysql` and you write `MS SQL Server`. What is right?

Comment: I tried DISTINCT and TOP 1 but they didn't work. << can you give more explanation? what is output and expected output. Simple sample is ok

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The Community Bot doesn't like the question either. At least do what the Bot asks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY delivery_date) AS RowNumber
  FROM wherever
  WHERE whatever
) T
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Or if you want the first from each warehouse:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY warehouse ORDER BY delivery_date) AS RowNumber
  FROM wherever
  WHERE whatever
) T
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```